# To speak selected language in Talkback - Android

Tags: android, talkback

I've added talkback functionality on my application.

Its working good. Talkback functionality is working in English language.

My problem is , when i change the device language settings, my application working still in English language only. but when i checked other application , talk back are working in selected language.

What to do to speak selected language in my application using talkback.

Answer (score 2):

The selected language for TalkBack is independent of the system language, as stated in Google's [Eyes-Free FAQ](http://eyes-free.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/documentation/android_access/faq.html):

> *Is Android available in multiple languages?* Yes, the system already works in many languages, you can change it in the Settings. Each speech engine has support for a different set of languages for text-to-speech as well, but they're controlled independently of the system language.

You need to install the relevant language pack for your chosen text-to-speech (TTS) engine, e.g. Pico, and either set its language the same as the system language, or to 'automatic' if it supports that feature. The position of this setting has changed over time, for example:

- Android 2.2 (API 8): Menu->Settings->Voice Input and Output->Text-to-speech Settings
- Android 4.1 (API 16): Menu->Settings->Language and Input->Text-to-speech Settings

Your 'other application' may use a different `AccessibilityService`, e.g. ClockBack or internal support, which is causing the confusion.